# Physical interpretation of Glauber states

Tags: optics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics

The definition of a Glauber, or coherent, state is

$$a|\alpha\rangle = \alpha|\alpha\rangle.$$

Why is this a useful definition? Grynberg's Quantum Optics book simply says "a quasi-classical state $|\alpha\rangle$ is the eigenstate of the annihilation operator $a$.

Comment: relevant: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10391 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/90034 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/119104 http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89018

Comment: Ah darn. I was searching for Glauber states. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is a coherent state and why is it interesting?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119104/)